# Does scitools for python 3 exist?

Tags: python, anaconda, scitools

I'm currently working through the book "A Primer on Scientific Programming with Python", and one of the recommended packages to install is scitools. I have the Anaconda version of python 3.6 installed on a CentOS 7 machine. When I tried following the instructions in the text for installing scitools, I received an error message saying that python 2.7 is a dependency for the version of scitools I was trying to install, and that I was missing it.

So, I guess I'm asking if there is a version of scitools that works with python 3. If there is, can I install it with conda?

Comment: try to install from there: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: search for scitools_iris‑2.2.0‑py3‑none‑any.whl

Comment: https://github.com/hplgit/scitools/issues/21